# What is the source for printing the diamond in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a source that can input odd numbers into the user and print out diamond-shaped * accordingly

example)

```
enter an odd number : 5



   *
  ***
 *****
  ***
   *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (example), input = 5, you just must learn, how to count:

```
(spaces)(stars)
   2       1
   1       3
   0       5
   1       3
   2       1
```

```js
let input = 7; // Number( prompt("Enter any odd integer") );
let space = "&nbsp;";

/*****/
let breakPoint = Math.floor(input / 2);

let str = "", iter = 0, i = 0;
while( iter < input ) {
  str += (
    space.repeat( (breakPoint - i) ) +
    "*".repeat( 2 * i + 1 ) +
    "<br>"
  );
  
  (iter < breakPoint) ? (i++) : (i--);
  iter++;
}

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

```css
body { font-family: 'Lucida Console'; } /* Monospaced font required */
```

One loop might be confusing. I came to it after trying two separate loops:

```js
let input = 7;
let space = " ";

/***/

let breakPoint = Math.ceil(input / 2);

let str = "";

for( let i = 0; i < breakPoint - 1; i++ ) {
  str += (
    space.repeat( (breakPoint - i) ) +
    "*".repeat( 2 * i + 1 ) +
    "\n"
  );
}

for( let i = breakPoint - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
  str += (
    space.repeat( (breakPoint - i) ) +
    "*".repeat( 2 * i + 1 ) +
    "\n"
  );
}

console.log( str );
```

Or, KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid):

```js
let input = 7;
let space = " ";

/***/

let breakPoint = Math.floor(input / 2); // 3

let str = "";

let spaces = breakPoint; // (3)
let stars = 1;

for( let i = 0; i < breakPoint; i++ ) {
  str += (
    space.repeat(spaces) +
    "*".repeat(stars) +
    "\n"
  );
  
  spaces -= 1;
  stars += 2;
}

for( let i = breakPoint; i >= 0; i-- ) {
  str += (
    space.repeat(spaces) +
    "*".repeat(stars) +
    "\n"
  );
  
  spaces += 1;
  stars -= 2;
}

console.log( str );
```